# Create a regex to extract a string that contain a noral character and escaped string without DOS

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like this:

```
///////AB?\a\b\c\d\d\e\\f\a\a\b\cd\ed\fmnopqrstuvwxy\z\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a\a///imgy
```

it started with `///` and ended with `///imgy` (i and/or m and/or g and/or y), and between the beginning and end are the character are normal character like `a` or escaped character like `\a`.

Here is my regex:

```
/^\/{3}((?:\\?[\s\S])+?)\/{3}([imgy]{0,4})(?!\w)/
```

But the problem is that it is reported as "vulnerable to denial-of-service attacks". The main part that has the problem is

```
(?:\\?[\s\S])+
```

How can I create a right one that can figure out both `a` and `\a`? Thank you!

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jFAnHT/1)

**Update:**

I just found to use the following regex:

```
(?:\\[\s\S]+?)|(?:(?<!\\)[\s\S]+?)|(?:(?<=\\\\)[\s\S]+?)
```

to replace the old problematic part `(?:\\?[\s\S])+?`, and in this way, it can avoid requires exponential time to match certain inputs, and avoid vulnerable to denial-of-service attacks.

The details:

1. `(?:\\[\s\S]+?)` match any `\a`
2. `(?:(?<!\\)[\s\S]+?)` match any `a`, but not following `\`.
3. `(?:(?<=\\\\)[\s\S]+?)` match any `a`, but much following `\\`. This to make sure `f` is matched that following `\\`.

So the whole regex will look like this:

```
^\/{3}((?:\\[\s\S]+?)|(?:(?<!\\)[\s\S]+?)|(?:(?<=\\\\)[\s\S]+?))\/{3}([imgy]{0,4})(?!\w)
```

Comment: can there be more `/` in the middle? I think of `/\/{3,}[^\/]*\/{3}[imgy]{0,4}(?!\w)/`

Comment: The ```/``` should be allowed. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You might list the characters that are allowed to a character class, and optionally repeat an escaped character `[a-z]`

```
^\/{3,}[A-Za-z?]+(?:\\[a-z\\][A-Za-z?]*)*\/\/\/[imgy]{0,4}$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `\/{3,}[A-Za-z?]+` Match 3 or more `/` and 1 or more times any of the listed allowed chars
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\\[a-z\\]` Match an escaped char a-z or `\\`
  - `[A-Za-z?]*` Optionally match any of the listed
- `)*` Close an optionally repeat the group
- `\/\/\/[imgy]{0,4}` Match `///` and 0-4 times any of `i` `m` `g` or `y` If there should be at least a single char, you can use `{1,4}`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GjQYwn/1)

Comment: Thank you! The string begin with ```///```. And should also allow ```/``` in the middle.

Comment: @Liqun Sun You can use https://regex101.com/r/ctOCIo/1